# Can I re-use a PreparedStatement if it hits a transient exception?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb

I have a block of code which updates records in a database. Reduced example:

```
...
statement = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO thistable (name) VALUES (?)",
    PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
);
statement.setString( 1, "Fred" );
statement.addBatch( );
statement.setString( 2, "Joe" );
statement.addBatch( );
statement.executeBatch( );
...
```

This is part of some code which is processing a *lot* of records, and the code is running a lot of threads for speed. That's all fine, but as the load increases on the live environment, I've been noticing a few `SQLTransientException`s being thrown. It seems I can't do anything about these except retry the transaction.

My question is: could the batch have been cleared even though the statement failed? Am I OK to simply retry the `executeBatch` line, or do I need to re-create the entire batch? And is this the same for non-batch statements?

---

In short, and more generally, is this a good way to handle transient exceptions?

```
statement.setString( 1, "Fred" );
statement.addBatch( );
statement.setString( 2, "Joe" );
statement.addBatch( );
for( int attempt = 0; ; attempt ++ ) {
    try {
        statement.executeBatch( );
        break;
    } catch( SQLTransientException ex ) {
        if( attempt >= 3 ) {
            throw ex;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep( attempt * attempt * 100 );
        } catch( InterruptedException ex2 ) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tagged this question MySQL because that's what we're currently using, but I'm looking to understand the standard behaviour, rather than implementation-specific behaviour, since we're migrating to Postgres soon.

Comment: In theory `SQLTransientException` should only be thrown if the error allows for operations that can be retried without "without any intervention by application-level functionality".

Comment: Do you have any SQL State for this Exception (getSQLState())?

Comment: @Mani, afraid I didn't know that existed so I haven't been logging it.

Comment: @user2574853's answer-comment: Though the example I've posted doesn't illustrate it, the 10 or so records which are added by each batch really are a batch; they all relate to the same item, and if any of them fail there is no point adding the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) does not provide much information about the behavior when SQLTransientException happens apart from below

```
 when the driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by the 
 setQueryTimeout method has been exceeded and has at least attempted
 to cancel the currently running Statement
```

Verified the Mysql JDBC4 Implementation .

In my observation, I could see there is one possible `SQLTimeoutException` (i.e `SQLTransientException` ) can happen if the timed out.

And while timed out , it is not just clearing the last statements , it is clearing entire Batch ( at least in MYSQL Implementation )

```
// we timeout the entire batch, not individual statements
```

So that part is clear.

And as per JDBC Specification

```
The statement’s batch is reset to empty once executeBatch returns
```

Irrespective of executeBatch throws exception / succeed it would clear the Batch .

Specifically Mysql `Prepared Statement`  clears the batch at finaly block in executeBatch() method

```
finally {
        this.statementExecuting.set(false);
        clearBatch();
        }
```

So your logic will not work, since you are not adding the statements into batch again.

So add the statements back to batch and re-execute . there are highly possible you might end up in Timeout again. So first find the time out . if possible write some information about cause / state in the execution logs.

Comment: Manually clearing (just in case) and re-populating it is then. It's a pity - I was hoping this could be hidden away in a method.

Comment: Just to add (for future visitors) that for the related question about non-batch statements, the values do not need to be re-populated, according to this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#clearParameters()

Answer (score 0):

what's the exception message? Not sure if it failed due to mysql connection issue. Furthermore, I don't think it's good to process a long request. You could run it multiple times by running piece by piece in order to achieve your target.

Comment: Answered this in the comments on the question. For future reference, you should not post comments/questions as answers.